# Relative compactness in topological spaces (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, compactness, nets

**Motivation and context:** For a subset $S$ of a metric space $(M,d)$, the following are two very classical compactness results in Analysis:

- **1a)** The set $S$ is compact if and only if each sequence in $S$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $S$.
- **1b)** The set $S$ is relatively compact (i.e., has compact closure) in $M$ if and only if each sequence in $S$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $M$.

Now consider the following analogous claims for a subset $S$ of a topological space $X$:

- **2a)** The set $S$ is compact if and only if each net in $S$ has a subnet that converges to a point in $S$.
- **2b)** The set $S$ is relatively compact in $X$ if and only if each net in $S$ has a subnet that converges to a point in $X$.

Assertion 2a) is also a classical result in point set topology. On the other hand, the implication "$\Leftarrow$" in 2b) does **not** hold, in general.

**More precisely, the following holds:**

- **(i)** If $X$ is not Hausdorff, it may happen that $S$ is compact but not closed, and also has non-compact closure. This shows that 2b) fails, in general.
- **(ii)** A bit more interestingly, 2b) can also fail in Hausdorff spaces. Indeed, a counterexample can be constructed if we chose $S$ to be an open half disc with one additional point, in the *half-disc topology* on the upper half plane; this topology is, for instance, described in Example 78 of Steen and Seebach's "[Counterexamples in Topology](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-6290-9) (1978)".
  (It is not stated explicitly there that this space yields a counterexample for 2b), but that's not difficult to see.)
- **(iii)** If $X$ is Hausdorff and the topology on $X$ is induced by a [uniform structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) (equivalently, if $X$ is [completely regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space)), then 2b) does indeed hold.

Assertion (iii) is not extremely difficult to show, but it is not completely obvious, either. Moreover, (iii) is sometimes quite useful in operator theory. So for the sake of citation, the following question arises:

**Question** (reference request): Do you know a reference where (iii) is explicitly stated and proved?

**Related question:** [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30662/102946) is loosely related.

Comment: Not sure if you will find it there, but I would take a look on the Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations, by Eric Schechter.

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba: Ha, great! Schechter indeed has the result, namely in Section 17.15 (on page 460). It is even true on [regular spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space), not only on completely regular ones. Thanks a lot! If you post this as an answer, I'll of course accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I'll post it then :)

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba: Thanks for posting the answer!  By the way, this Handbook by Schechter is incredible! I've dreamed about such a book for years (but didn't know it really exists - until today).

Comment: I found this book when I was studying about some equivalences of the ultrafilter lemma, back in 2016. Since then it is my favorite book, and even an inspiration for my own book.

Comment: Concerning the “counterexamples” in (i), I would argue that you use the wrong definition of "relatively compact". In a not necessarily Hausdorff space the natural definition is IMHO the following: $M\subseteq X$ is relatively compact in $X$ if there is a compact $K\subseteq X$ with $M\subseteq K$. With this definition, the “counterexamples” in (i) become empty.

Comment: @MartinVäth: Good point. While, in the above question, I'm mostly interested in the Hausdorff case (I just mentioned (i) "for the sake of completenss"), I agree that one might find your definition of relative compactness more natural. I've browsed a bit of literature: Bourbaki use your definition, too (but, as one would expect from Bourbaki, they call it *relatively quasi-compact*), while Schechter's handbook mentioned in the comments and in the answer uses the definition from my question. Several other books don't mention the term "relatively compact" at all.

Comment: @MartinVäth: Your comment motivated me to have a look at your book *Topological Analysis* (2012), where you define relative compactness in Definition 2.31. Within the range of books that I looked at today, this now makes 2:1 for your definition. ;-) (But as mentioned before, I find your definition conceptually quite convincing anyway. So thanks again for your comment.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the *Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations*, by Eric Schechter (Section 17.15).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that even $T_3$ is already sufficient. I do not have access to the monograph Fletcher, Peter and Lindgren, William F., Quasi-uniform spaces, M. Dekker, New York, Basel 1982, in the moment, but this contains quite some results about completion and quasi-compactness. Perhaps it also contains results about the relation to relative compactness.

Comment: Indeed, it is true in $T_3$-spaces. For instance, the *Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations* mentioned in Renan Maneli Mezabarba's answer states the result in $T_3$-spaces (in Section 17.15). I also had a look at the book *Quasi-uniform spaces* that you suggested: while I could not find exactly the same result there, the corollary to Proposition 3.15 seems to be at least related. Thank you for the reference!